# cPanel email routing... if not found locally try remote

Tags: email, routes, cpanel

I've got a weird setup with my emails that I need someones brain to look at. I've got it setup like this so that most of my emails are on one server (server1) and then 1 single account is setup on a second server hidden from the rest (server2)

```
Email Sent to user1@domain.me
MX record for domain.me = mail.domain.me
A record for mail.domain.me = server1 (11.11.11.11)
Email forwarding rule forwards all email sent to user1@domain.me to user@2.domain.me

MX record for 2.domain.me = mail2.domain.me
A record for mail2.domain.me = server2 (22.22.22.22) a cpanel server

Email hits my server now addressed to user1@2.domain.me
Domain forwarding rule forwards all email sent to @2.domain.me to @domain.me
```

This works great however my mail routing in cpanel is set to local, and therefore when sending emails out on server2 (22.22.22.22) to users@domain.me they're always delivered locally first and foremost

Is there any way around this? so that outgoing mail on this domain obey's DNS records (the mx records) and delivers it firstly to server1 (11.11.11.11) as if it was being sent from any other domain, gmail etc. Perhaps if the account isn't found locally then send on out to the web? Or perhaps there is a way to setup an alias somehow to let the local account receive mail for user1@2.domain.me

Thanks for your time & efforts looking into this

Henry

Answer (score 0):

Check if your remote domains are listed in **/etc/remotedomains** and **/etc/secondarymx**. Note that if your second server has a dns server, it will try fetch the dns data locally first.

I have 2 servers using cpanel where each server acts as the other's backup and I don't have the issue you described.